# CPU burning hot causing internet connection to slow down (or cut off)

Tags: windows-7, cpu, virus, cooling, malware

I have an HP pavilion g6, 64 bit. I dualboot it, installing windows 7 and a linux distro. nowaday I'm running crunchbang linux distro.

When I'm working on any linux distro, i don't remember having any issues. But when i work on windows, My CPU burns so hot, even though i have a cooler, it almost cause the cooler plastic to melt.

I have noticed this issue happening especially when i use [orbit downloader](http://www.orbitdownloader.com/), or when i do a scan. i use [avg internet security 2013](http://www.avg.com/us-en/internet-security).

I used [speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy) to check the CPU temperature, sometimes it gets up to 95 degree Celsius (203 degree Fahrenheit). Sometimes even more.

This issue is recent, i don't recall having it last year. I tried cleaning the laptop fan and the cooler with a toothbrush and a hairdryer. The CPU now is much cooler, but when i use orbit downloader, i can hear the cpu running much faster and the internet cuts off, i have to restart my laptop, so that the CPU slows down, only then will the internet start working again.

I have used [Malwarebytes Rootkit Removal Tool](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/malwarebytes-anti-rootkit/) and [Malwarebytes](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/malwarebytes-anti-malware/) and [The Microsoft Rootkit Removal Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/security/pc-security/malware-removal.aspx). I was able to detect 9 viruses but the issue isn't completely solved. Even when i run malwarebytes, the cpu runs so fast, burns so hot and the internet is gone. i have to restart my laptop.

Many software cause this issue, but orbit downloader causes it much more often.

Comment: Check your power settings, do you have it set on "Quiet" or similar?

Comment: @Fischer Is not using `Orbit Downloader` a program that presents nothing but problems an option?  It still sounds like you have a cooling problem.

Comment: @terdon i have tried all the power options that i have `power saver`, `balanced` and `high performance`, it doesn't seem to make much of a difference, when the cpu starts running fast, the only way to make it slow down is to restart the pc, sometimes `sleep mode` helps, but sometimes restart is the only way

Comment: @terdon yes maybe a cooling problem but why would a cooling problem cut off the internet? as for `orbit downloader` i could stop using it, if i find an alternative, `idm` isn't free and `fdm` is not that good either, when it comes to download manager, orbit is the best free one i have found

Comment: maybe you have virus on Windows OS?

Comment: @Dilshod i doubt that, i have scanned and removed the viruses and scanned again, there's nothing more i can do

Comment: did you check the task manager? How are processes doing? which one is hogging the CPU?

Comment: @Dilshod  i think i know what's happening now! it's google chrome that is eating my cpu!